# What should a Rails 3.x noob know about maintaining a Rails 2.3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I recently learned Rails (*Rails 3* to be specific) and got a small project maintaining a *Rails 2.3.2* app.

So, as you might expect, I keep running into differences between what I learned in Rails 3 and what I'm working in.

For example 'rails server' command in Rails 3 is 'script/server' in Rails 2.x.

What else should I know to maintain my sanity?

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to rails, I don't know if you'll see a lot of differences. The rails server command is one thing however.

The other big thing is the use of .gemspec in Rails 2.3.5 instead of Bundler and Gemfiles in Rails 3. Installing gems/specifying which gems your app uses is way better in Rails 3 I think.

The rest are mostly syntax changes and depreciated functions in specific areas (e.g. javascript generators).

[This Blog](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3) does a good job of listing most of the major changes in more detail.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks.  And yes, I know about the lack of bundler, and have to say, I had no idea how awesome bundler was until I discovered life without it.